# How to print out list of previous input for specific weekday?

Tags: python

I want my program to print out a specific list for the current weekday (e.g. today is Wednesday).
For Wednesday I created a list of 3 items.
My program should recognize which day it is (real-world) and accordingly output the list for said day.

```
# imports
import time
import datetime

# definition
date = time.strftime("%A")
Wednesday = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

# code
if datetime.datetime.today().stfrtime("%A") == Wednesday:
    print (Wednesday)
    time.sleep(0.5)
time.sleep(2)
print()
menu = int(input("Please choose an item by typing in a number: "))-1
```

Based on the list of available items, the user should have the option to chose one of the items on the list. After the user chooses the item, the program should print the users item choice accordingly.

Comment: What is your actual question? You probably mean `'Wednesday'` as a string, not a variable with that name (which is what it means without quotes).

Comment: I want the program to know the current day of the week and accordingly first print out the list for that day and then after the user chooses one item from the list it prints out only the item from that list.
Something like:
`print (Great! You chose this item:` and then it prints out the item the user inputted.

Comment: You seem to be restating information which is already in the question. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: A better arrangement is to have a single dictionary with the weekdays as keys; so `memory = {'Wednesday': ["item1", "item2", "item3"], 'Thursday': [], etc }` and then just `print(memory[time.strftime("%A")])` to get the list for today.

Comment: I don't know how to make it output the item of the users input.

Comment: `print(memory[time.strftime("%A")][menu])`

Comment: As an aside, adding `time.sleep()` in your code only makes it more frustrating to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary where key `0` has your items for Monday, key `1` has your items for Tuesday and so on. Then, use `datetime.datetime.today().weekday()` to get the number of the current day:

```
import datetime

dct = {0: ['monday items'],
       1: ['tuesday items'],
       2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
       4: ['and so on']}

items = dct[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()]

print(f"Please choose an item from this list: {', '.join(items)}")
```